# bad_alloc preempted in VS 2010/2013 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This simple example works as expected in g++, but in MS VS 2010 or 2013 shows a runtime library debug error (Invalid allocation size) before the error is caught (clicking Ignore does then flow through the error handler showing it correctly to be a bad_alloc).
Any ideas about why VS behaves this way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x;
    cout << "Enter -1 for bad_alloc: ";
    cin >> x;
    try
    {
        int* myarray = new int[x];
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << "Standard exception: " << e.what() << endl;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is just the debugger and/or debug library that does that, if you run without debugger/as release version it won't.

Comment: Turns out it is. Thought I had checked that, but I hadn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's so that you can analyse the exception at the point it is thrown, before the stack is unwound.

It's a *feature* that the debugger does this for you.

Nothing to worry about here.